# Magento: Object not found in localhost

Tags: php, magento, localhost

I'm trying to copy website made in Magento in my localhost and finished another steps:

- downloaded whole website via ftp account,
- import database from server,
- change parameters for database in local.xml (post **root** for user and    empty
  field for password),
- clear cache in Magento **var** folder,
- change base_url value in database

When I try to open it in browser, Homepage looks ok, but any link in page give me **Error 404 - Object not found**. I can't access to admin panel. Anything what I type URL after localhost/nameOfMyProject, I get Error 404.

I have 2 other Magento projects in my localhost and they work correctly, but both of them I installed from fresh Magento installation and then add new themes for them.

Here is different situation. I need to add whole existing project from server in localhost. I can't add this website on same way, because developer who made it changed files into **core** section. Project is too big it's not possible at the moment to change that, so any way is to download whole project in localhost.

Does anyone has some suggestion what to do?

Best Regards,
Mladja

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check you also downloaded the .htaccess file and mod-rewrite is enabled in your apache conf.

To access to admin panel try: `localhost/nameOfMyProject/index.php/admin`

Comment: not working here , do i need to download htaccess ?